perl: After "perl Makefile.PL", make quietly dies with error code 127
Greetings after a loooong hiatus.
I am working this in Windows-7 (crotchety reactionary, I ;-) under Cygwin-64.
I am revisiting a Perl module I posted to CPAN over 10 years ago.  Specifically: Math::Yapp .
My After un-tar-ing the file I go into the directory Math-Yapp-1.07 (under my Downloads folder) and, as per standard directions:
$ perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Math::Yapp
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

So far, so good.  The next step is a simple make. Or is supposed to be so.  However, that produces no output for me.  Sinking feeling here...
$ make
$ echo $?
127

So some command that make is trying to run was not found.  But even make --debug=VERBOSE generates no output and exits with $? at 127!
The module was originally created under Perl 5.014 and I am running 5.036. Here is the complete
Makefile.PL:
use 5.014002;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
# See lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm for details of how to influence
# the contents of the Makefile that is written.
WriteMakefile(
    NAME              => 'Math::Yapp',
    VERSION_FROM      => 'lib/Math/Yapp.pm', # finds $VERSION
    PREREQ_PM         => {}, # e.g., Module::Name => 1.1
    ($] >= 5.005 ?     ## Add these new keywords supported since 5.005
      (ABSTRACT_FROM  => 'lib/Math/Yapp.pm', # retrieve abstract from module
       AUTHOR         => '(*my name*) <(*my email address*)>') : ()),
);

I doubt that many folks on this forum have experienced this and have a magical solution.  But at least some way to force some information out of make could be of help here!  This worked in the past.
Grateful for some help here.
-- A frustrated Jake..
As mentioned in the main text:
make --debug=VERBOSE
I expected SOME output to see where the make is failing.
In response to Chobora and GM:
Choroba, the fact that entering "make" did not generate a "command not found" indicates it is indeed installed. Ah, as per G.M., what version is it? Well you hit on something there, GM: 'make --version' produced no output either and also left a 127 exit code.
So, what version of make do I have? Going to the Cygwin setup I see I have 4.4.1-2, a development version. YIKES! So if y'all know of another variant of make (not imake) we might get somewhere.
Taking MadScientist's advice to change the tags, since the issue is make on cygwin.  Interesting that I don't find a gmake, since I do have gcc and g++. Not even in the setup.
2024-11-01:
After I posted the error box I had gotten from the strace make command I realized there was output on the command window.  Here's that output:
$ strace make
--- Process 93164 created
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 0000000077ba0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 0000000077a80000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 000007fefd7d0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll at 000007fe9fcc0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygguile-3.0-1.dll at 000000055a860000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygcrypt-2.dll at 00000003dc0d0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygffi-8.dll at 00000004e3e60000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cyggc-1.dll at 00000004c4d40000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll at 000000050caa0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cyggmp-10.dll at 00000004029c0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygiconv-2.dll at 00000003d7bc0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygintl-8.dll at 00000005ee2d0000
--- Process 93164 loaded C:\cygwin64\bin\cygunistring-5.dll at 00000004a6da0000
--- Process 93164, exception c0000139 at 0000000077c685b8
--- Process 93164 exited with status 0xc0000139

So that exception must be where it failed to load that entry point mbrtoc32.

The fact that make --debug=VERBOSE generates no output at all (really?) is a bit suspicious.  Please [edit] your question to show the output of make --version?

Do you have make installed?

Are you sure you're calling the right make? Try calling it with the full path instead.


Did you try uninstalling make and re-isntalling it? 2. What is the output of type make? 3. What do you get when you run strace make?


That version is fine.  Why do you think it's a "development version"?  I don't know what the -2 is but presumably Cygwin has applied some extra patches.  Anyway, this has nothing to do with make per se.  If running with --version prints no output then make is not able to start properly which probably means there's something wrong with your cygwin setup or environment.  You'll need to remove all the "perl" stuff from your tags and add in "cygwin" stuff; this has nothing to do with Perl (or make, either).

'make --version' produced no output either : From this I would conclude that what you are running as make, is not the utility people generally know as make.

User1934428 - Can I call you just "user"?  ;-)  Your comment is most interesting - That what I am running as "make" is not the make utility I think it is.  I kinda think that's unlikely.   And yes, ikegami, I did try running strace and got a "missing entry point", something like mbrtoc mssing from cygwin.dll.  However, I lost the screen shot of that.  Will describe the result of uninstall/install in next comment.  Thanks all for  the suggestions so far.

Sorry to say: the reinstalled make didn't work any better; same 127 exit code.  But this time I got the screen shot, which I can't post in a comment.  Error mesage:

Procedure entry point mbrtoc32 could not be located in dynamic link library cygwin1.dll.  YIKES! (Oh, I said that already once.)  Back to setup: I see cygwin but no cygwin1.  And nothing specific to cygwin.dll.  Reinstall of that got same errors.

All the above was under Windows-7.  On the suspicion that I simply have a messed up Cygwin - like allowing updates that are incompatible with Window-7, I slid over to my Windows-11 machine.  After installing make (why didn't it come with g++?) I ran it in an empty directory.  I got the expected "no target" error.  Some time next week I will try to install my Math::Yapp package on that machine and we'll see how that goes.  Giving this a rest for the weekend.

There is no solution in Cygwin under Windows-7.
How did I come to this conclusion?  I had installed the Guardian browser so my daughter could take an online exam.  It barfed at its startup with an almost identical error.  The instructor told her she needs to do it on at least Windows-10.  I am redoing the project on my Windows-11 PC and the make works just fine.
Yeah, I suppose I could download the source code for make and compile it on my Windows-7 Cygwin but it's time to acknowledge that times has passed me by on that OS.  Nostalgia, as the Borg might say, is irrelevant. And persistence is futile. (I don't think they ever said that!)
